# GET request works on browser but fails on Android app with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to request data from an API using the GET request. It works well on browser as I'm able to see the JSON response, but when I try to use the same request on my Android app I get a Forbidden message from the response, no JSON object. I'm using Retrofit for my GET request. Am I formatting my request correctly when using Retrofit? Here's the URL

```
    http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=MY_API_KEY
```

My ApiService file

```
    private const val BASE_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com"
    
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
  
    interface MovieApiService {
        @GET("/")
        fun getMovieInfo(@Query("i") imdbID: String, @Query("apikey") key: String): Call<String>
    }
```

My function

```
    private fun getMovieInfo() {
        val apiKey = BuildConfig.API_KEY
        MovieApi.retrofitService.getMovieInfo("tt3896198", apiKey).enqueue(
            object : Callback<String> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                    _response.value = response.message()
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                   _response.value = "Failure: ${t.message}"
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: What message exactly it shows as response?

Do you have a valid api key?

Your query looks correct.

Comment: The message is a string with the value = "Forbidden" when calling response.message() in the onResponse function.

Comment: `It works well on browser` A browser on your Android device?

Comment: Clear text traffic requested in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the API key is not going properly and thus it is coming in as forbidden. Here is how I suggest you try

```kotlin
private const val BASE_URL = "https://omdbapi.com/"
    
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
  
    interface MovieApiService {
        @GET("?apikey=your_api_key")  // Add your API key directly here
        fun getMovieInfo(@Query("i") imdbID: String): Call<String>
    }
```

Your key is attached directly to the request here and we are adding your query afterwards.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm still getting the "Forbidden" response.  The URL has the api key appended at the end, this solution appends it at the start. Is there a way to append the api key at the end, after the query?

Comment: I don't think the appending order matters. Try appending it at front and running in browser. I might be wrong. Also I think you are missing the header. Try adding that too once @DavidWekesa

Comment: You're right, the order doesn't matter. It still works on the browser. I've also checked the API docs and they haven't specified any headers that need to be added to the request.

Comment: Can you check out response.raw() and tell us what that is?

Comment: You can try requesting clearTraffic in your manifest. That is the only thing I can think of.